# Beautiful Soup get the second attribute from element

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
all_cells = result.find_all('div')
test = all_cells[1].find('a')
```

Which normally return this line

```
<a data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-html='true' title="<img src='https://l.jpg'>" href='details.php?id=234' title='sometext'><b>anothertext</b></a>
```

I want to get the content of the second "title" attribute (**sometext** in my example) but also to consider that sometimes the first "title" attribute is missing. As example when the first attribute is missing this will return the info i need.

```
testok = test['title']
```

Comment: When i load that html into beautiful soup I get `<a data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="details.php?id=234" title="&lt;img src='https://l.jpg'&gt;"><b>anothertext</b></a>` which does not match your printout.  html in most cases does not support two of the same attribute.

Comment: perhaps your issue would be more clear if you provide which site this html is from.  Knowing the source code might help someone solve the issue you're having.